# How to compile nanopb .proto file into .h and .c files using nanopb and protobuf (`protoc` compile question)

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-c, nanopb

Old title: How to compile nanopb/examples/simple/simple.proto file into simple.h and simple.c using nanopb and protobuf

Regarding this library: https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb

My goal is to follow this tutorial: https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/concepts.html to convert **nanopb/examples/simple/simple.proto** into a .h and .c source file. I need simple instructions to do this on Ubuntu. I've been attempting it for days and am unable to get it to work.

The commands the tutorial says to do are:

```
protoc -omessage.pb message.proto
python ../generator/nanopb_generator.py message.pb
```

I cloned the nanopb repo, cd'ed into **nanopb/examples/simple**, and then substituting in `simple.proto` instead of `message.proto` in the commands above, I ran the following:

```
protoc -osimple.pb simple.proto
```

It worked fine, producing a simple.pb file.

The 2nd part, however, fails. When running from inside the **nanopb/examples/simple** folder, I get:

```
$ python ../../generator/nanopb_generator.py simple.pb

         ********************************************************************
         *** Failed to import the protocol definitions for generator.     ***
         *** You have to run 'make' in the nanopb/generator/proto folder. ***
         ********************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../generator/nanopb_generator.py", line 39, in <module>
    import proto.nanopb_pb2 as nanopb_pb2
  File "/home/gabriels/GS/dev/Protocol_Buffers/Nanopb/source/nanopb/generator/proto/nanopb_pb2.py", line 11, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
ImportError: cannot import name symbol_database
```

Running `make` does nothing (says it's already done):

```
nanopb/generator/proto $ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Note that I am running the latest version of `protoc`, built from the Google protobuf repo from source: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.

I have also sought help from nanopb here, but am unable to figure it out, and feel like there's something basic here I'm missing because I just don't know enough: https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/issues/417. Feels like I'm beating my head into the wall on something that should be simple and has already been done by at least 1448+ people before me (the number of stars on nanopb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. @PetteriAimonen had [given me the missing clue](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/issues/417#issuecomment-517619517):

> the protoc version needs to match with the python library version

Then it occurred to me: originally, when compiling protobuf from scratch, I followed only the C++ installation instructions, as shown here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src. But, what if I follow the Python installation instructions too? https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/python

So, that's what I did.

### TLDR; Do the Python installation of the `protobuf` library too (not just the C++ installation):

Protobuf Python installation steps I followed:

```
python -V # See if I have Python 2.7 or newer (I must to continue)
cd protobuf/python # cd into Python source directory
python setup.py build
python setup.py test
(cd .. && make)
(cd .. && sudo make install)
python setup.py build --cpp_implementation
python setup.py test --cpp_implementation  # look to see all tests pass
sudo python setup.py install
```

## Two-step compile of .proto files:

That all worked, so now lets go back and try compiling our simple.proto file again.

`cd` into **nanopb/examples/simple**. We already ran the first command to produce the simple.pb file, so now just run the 2nd command that previously would fail, and it works!

2nd Command only:

```
nanopb/examples/simple $ python ../../generator/nanopb_generator.py simple.pb
```

Output:

> ```
> nanopb/examples/simple $ python ../../generator/nanopb_generator.py simple.pb  
> Writing to simple.pb.h and simple.pb.c
> ```

2-commands shown together again for completeness:

```
protoc -osimple.pb simple.proto
nanopb/examples/simple $ python ../../generator/nanopb_generator.py simple.pb
```

Beautiful! IT WORKED! **simple.pb.h** and **simple.pb.c** are now created!

Now build the "simple" project:

```
make
```

And run it:

```
./simple
```

And the output is:

> ```
> nanopb/examples/simple $ ./simple  
> Your lucky number was 13!
> ```

Now I can study the project to see how **simple.proto** was turned into **simple.pb.h** and **simple.pb.c**, and I can study **simple.c** (which contains the `main()` function) to see a full usage of these auto-generated .h and .c files, including looking at the following header files which it includes:

```
#include <pb_encode.h> # found up 2 levels, in "nanopb" folder
#include <pb_decode.h> # found up 2 levels, in "nanopb" folder
#include "simple.pb.h" # just generated right here in "nanopb/examples/simple" folder
```

## One-line command to build .proto files:

Instead of doing the **two-line command to build .proto files**:

```
# From inside folder "/home/gabriels/GS/dev/Protocol_Buffers/Nanopb/source/nanopb/examples/simple":
protoc -osimple.pb simple.proto
python ../../generator/nanopb_generator.py simple.pb
```

we can do a **one-line command to build .proto files** which just uses the `protoc` executable plus the `protoc-gen-nanopb` plugin:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-nanopb=/home/gabriels/GS/dev/Protocol_Buffers/Nanopb/source/nanopb/generator/protoc-gen-nanopb --nanopb_out=. simple.proto
```

And then, of course, we still need to **make and run** the main C project:

```
# From inside folder "/home/gabriels/GS/dev/Protocol_Buffers/Nanopb/source/nanopb/examples/simple":
make && ./simple
```